# How to create stacked icons using angular material icons?

Tags: angular-material, google-material-icons

I have found "Material Design Iconic Font" library which is similar to md-icon and allow to create a stacked icon:
http://zavoloklom.github.io/material-design-iconic-font/examples.html

But wasn't able to create a stacked icon combining angular material icons.
https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdIcon

I'm already using angular material icons in my project, and don't want to include another library just for stacked icon.

Is there any way/work around we can combine md-icons to create a stacked angular material icons?

Answer (score 1):

I laso had this problem once, if you want to do that you will need to use CSS for that.

Create 2 icon tags, put them in a container tag, and give this container a class.

Now you need to use CSS to stack the icons.

(you might want to set the position of the 3 tags to `relative` so they stack easily).